# Order email not send to admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi guys it seems that woocommerce will not let me receive emails for a new order, canceled orders, etc. I found that the problem was if I have the "From" Address the same as the Recipient(s) it will not send. But if there are different email it works fine. Is there some way to make this work because I do not want to use my personal email. Thanks

Comment: have you checked set in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails (tab)

Comment: @sameersheikh Hey , Yes I have everything seems to be fine.